# How to locate problematic (un-picklable) object?

Tags: python, pickle

Trying to pickle an object, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

The object class in question inherits another class (pytorch_lightning.LightningModule), so I assume the problematic object belongs to the super class. How can I locate it? The error trace only leads up to my pickling command, which is

```
with open(save_path, "wb") as p:
    pickle.dump(self, p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) you can influence on how an object is pickled by defining [`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) function.

> Classes can further influence how their instances are pickled; if the
>   class defines the method `__getstate__()`, it is called and the returned
>   object is pickled as the contents for the instance, instead of the
>   contents of the instance’s dictionary. If the `__getstate__()` method is
>   absent, the instance’s `__dict__` is pickled as usual.

Try to do the following:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    for variable_name, value in vars(self).items():
        try:
            pickle.dumps(value)
        expect:
            print('{variable_name} with value {value} is not pickable')
```

When you will try to pickle the object it should print out the *un-picklable* objects of your object.

#### Alternative way:

> If the `__getstate__()` method is
>   absent, the instance’s `__dict__` is pickled as usual.

Go over the object `__dict__` in the same way, try to pickle each one of the variables to find out the problematic ones.

Comment: Nice. should be pretty easy to extend recursively to find out exactly where in the hierarchy the offending object\s are. Though I feel that the pickling procedure itself should have done that

Comment: I don't think you need to 'extend it recursively' because `vars()` give you the object `__dict__` which contain all the super classes variables as well.

Comment: Well yes, but what if the offending variable belongs to an object which belongs to another object which ... which belongs to the super class? There are scenarios where it would be nice to know where precisely it is located

Comment: Check if `inspect` can help you with that.
Use `inspect.getmro` to get all the classes that your object is inherit from and `inspect.getclosurevars` to get all the inherited classes `__init__` variables.